# navigating a login/sign up php stack

Tags: php, sql, github, mamp

I've been following a [12 file login/sign up tutorial on github](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal) for the past week or so. I can't seem to get this stack to work at all...

Here is the play by play:

```
01-create-database.sql //simple statements to create db; (success!)

02-create-and-fill-users-table.sql //simple statements to create tables; (success!)

Login.php //handles user login and logout (saved to htdocs)

Registration.php //handles user registration (saved to htdocs)

db.php //configuration for database connection

password_compatibility_library.php //A Compatibility library with PHP 5.5's simplified password hashing API.

.htaccess //This file prevents that your .php view files are accessed directly from the outside

logged_in.php //echos user info

not_logged_in.php ////potential errors and login form

register.php //register form

index.php (make over) //more info on db connection

register.php (make over) //potential errors and login form
```

My questions:

- how do I successfully save a `.htaccess` file?
- When I try to save this small file with the path suggested on github; `.htaccess`, my code editor doesn't highlight the code to show recognition. I also get a popup from my operating system (OS X Yosemite) saying something along the lines of 'names with. extensions are reserved for the system' so i gathered it was invalid.
- Why is the raw script showing up in the browser and not the elements; i copied the code exactly and saved them to htdocs?

I also have a qualm with the db.php file

```
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_NAME", "login");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "mysql");
```

Are these statements changing my configuration radically? This is the default settings for the `MAMPP` version i just installed

```
Host    localhost
Port    3306
User    root
Password    root
Socket  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Do the statement's i listed in the **db.php** file over-write the typical;

```
mysql> grant all privileges on login.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

Any tips on a restart?

Comment: "//This file prevents that your .php view files are accessed directly from the outside" this makes no sense; a .php file would be executed, not displayed in the browser, so the code wouldn't be directly displayed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/opensavehide.htm) says:

View Hidden Files and Folders in an ‘Open’ or ‘Save’ Dialog Box

- Launch the application you wish to use to edit or view the hidden
  file.
- Select ‘Open’ from the application’s File menu.
- An Open Dialog box will display.
- With the dialog box as the front-most window (you can click once in the dialog box to make sure
  it’s in front), press the command, shift, and period keys at the same time.
- The dialog box now will display any hidden files or folders within its list items.
- You can toggle between the hidden files and folders being displayed by pressing command, shift, 
  period again.
- Once the hidden files and folders display in the dialog box, you can navigate and open the files 
  just as you would any other file in the Finder.

This same trick also works for ‘Save’ and ‘Save As Dialog’ boxes.

Your second question: "...qualm with the db.php file"
This file just lets your application know how to access the database. You'd replace values there to match your database. I don't know if they are suggesting to use the DB root user, or if they just did that to fill space.

Comment: i still need to be certain that i'm saving the file in the right place to begin with